# Define an operator $T\in B(C[0,1])$ such that: $(Tf)(x)=xf(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $f\in C[0,1]$. Prove that $T$ has no eignvalues

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, continuity, operator-theory

Define an operator $T\in B(C[0,1])$ such that:
$(Tf)(x)=xf(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$ and $f\in C[0,1]$.
Prove that $T$ has no eignvalues and find $\sigma(T)$.

I think that what is meant is to show that there are no $\lambda\in C$ such that $Tf(x)=\lambda f(x)$.

By contradiction:
$Tf(x)=\lambda f(x)$= {by definition} = $xf(x)$.

However this equation is true iff $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, however we're given that $f\in C[0,1]$.

The spectrum of T is:
All the scalars $\lambda$ such that $\lambda*I-T$ is not invertible.
I am not sure if it is fine to connect that with the first part.
Since T has no eign-values so $T-I$ is not injective then not invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do regarding the spectrum. You need to ask yourself when $T-\lambda I$ is invertible.

So we are asking ourselves when we can solve the equation $g(x)=(x-\lambda)f(x)$ for $f$. This forces us to write
$$
f(x)=\frac1{x-\lambda}\,g(x). 
$$
If the denominator is allowed to reach zero we cannot have $f$ as a continuous function. This shows that $T-\lambda I$ is invertible when $\lambda\not\in[0,1]$, and so $\sigma(T)\subset[0,1]$. When $\lambda\in[0,1]$, the function $g(x)=(x-\lambda)f(x)$ satisfies $g(\lambda)=0$. This shows that $T-\lambda I$ is not surjective, and hence not invertible. Thus $[0,1]\subset\sigma(T)$, and then
$$
\sigma(T)=[0,1]. 
$$
With the same idea you can show that if $Tf=hf$ for some $h\in C[0,1]$, then $\sigma(T)=h([0,1])$.

Comment: Thank you! @Martin Argerami , the last paragraph in your answer is a kind of a general case where we have a function h (not x), right?  And is the first part I did regarding eignvalues fine?

Comment: Yes and yes. Your exercise is the case $h(x)=x$.

Comment: Hello,  I feel like the first part I did is not quite fine, here $f\neq 0$ since it is a eignvector, but what about $\lambda\in [0,1]$ can it solve the equation $(\lambda-x)f=0$ ? Why we deduce that $T-\lambda I$ isn't surjective? Thanks! @Martin Argerami

Comment: You want $g$ continuous with $g(x)=(\lambda- x)f(x)$. So, on $[0,1]\setminus\{\lambda\}$, $f(x)=g(x)/(\lambda - x)$.  This forces $g(\lambda)=0$. So any $g$ with $g(\lambda)\ne0$ is not in the image of $T-\lambda I$.